# How do you do a "-" in python?

Tags: python

So this python code was given to me. It was implied that it worked, but clearly I am having issues. I am just wondering if anyone can tell me whats wrong?

The errors keep happening when I try to run

```
 intron1_length = ((my_dna.find(‘gtcata’)) –
 (my_dna.find(‘atcgat’)))
```

with the error being the "-". Just not sure what should go there instead. Thanks!

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

 # We’ll start with “data-aware” way to do this first.
 # Since we have the sequence, we can see that exon 1 ends with
 # ‘GACTA’. We can use that information, and that method, for
 # finding the positions of the elements of this gDNA. This is NOT
 # an elegant solution, and would not work if we didn’t know the
 # DNA sequence ahead of time.

 my_dna = "ATCGATCGATGGTCGAATGACTAgtcatagctatgcatgtagctactc
 gatcgtattttattcgatcgatcgatCGATCGATCATGCTATCATCGATCGATATCGATGCATC
 GACTACTATgtcatggctatgcatcgatcgtattttattcgatcgttcgatGATCGATCGATCGACTGACTTTGAA"   
 # here we introduce another useful operator for strings: len
 gene_length = len(my_dna)
 # we’ll use the starting position of useful substrings in the
 # sequence to find the positions of the exon-intron boundaries.
 # We’ll then use those to find the length of each segment.
 exon1_length = (my_dna.find('Agtcata'))
 intron1_length =((my_dna.find('gtcata')) - (my_dna.find('atcgat')))
 exon2_length = ((my_dna.find('CGATCG'))- (my_dna.find('Tgtcatg')))
 intron2_length = ((my_dna.find('gtcatg'))- (my_dna.find('tGATCGA')))
 exon3_length = (gene_length(my_dna.find('GATCGA'))
 print ("Gene length:" + str(gene_length))
 print ("Exon1 length:" + str(exon1_length))
 print ("Intron1 length:" + str(intron1_length))
 print ("Exon2 length:" + str(exon2_length))
 print ("Intron2 length:" + str(intron2_length))
 print ("Exon2 length:" + str(exon3_length))
```

Comment: `‘atcgat’` is not `'atcgat'`. Be sure you're actually using the right kind of quotes; "smart quotes" will mess up your code.

Comment: You're using a lot of unnecessary parentheses. I recommend cutting down on those; you have some bugs involving mismatched parentheses.

Comment: "errors keep happening" - please report the errors themselves. If you go to the doctor, you don't just strip naked and shout "examine me!", you tell him all the symptoms. What error, *specifically*, are you getting?

Comment: What is 'atcgat' suppose to be then? And a lot of errors are happening, I was under the impression the code worked but clearly not. Also I am running it on textwrangler through unix if that matters.

Comment: Odd - textwrangler says it _can_ be used for programming. Does you file have a `.py` extension?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using an editor with rainbow parens -- that way these mistakes are harder to miss.

Answer (score 5):

Because `–` != `-`

Whatever are you using to edit your code? A wordprocessor??

These quotes `‘` also look suspicious. Use an editor that doesn't put those in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The code below runs without error:

```
my_dna = """ATCGATCGATGGTCGAATGACTAgtcatagctatgcatgtagctactc
gatcgtattttattcgatcgatcgatCGATCGATCATGCTATCATCGATCGATATCGATGCATC
GACTACTATgtcatggctatgcatcgatcgtattttattcgatcgttcgatGATCGATCGATCGACTGACTTTGAA"""
# here we introduce another useful operator for strings: len
gene_length = len(my_dna)
# we’ll use the starting position of useful substrings in the
# sequence to find the positions of the exon-intron boundaries.
# We’ll then use those to find the length of each segment.
exon1_length = my_dna.find('Agtcata')
intron1_length = my_dna.find('gtcata') - my_dna.find('atcgat')
exon2_length = my_dna.find('CGATCG') - my_dna.find('Tgtcatg')
intron2_length = my_dna.find('gtcatg') - my_dna.find('tGATCGA')
exon3_length = gene_length - my_dna.find('GATCGA')
print ("Gene length:" + str(gene_length))
print ("Exon1 length:" + str(exon1_length))
print ("Intron1 length:" + str(intron1_length))
print ("Exon2 length:" + str(exon2_length))
print ("Intron2 length:" + str(intron2_length))
print ("Exon2 length:" + str(exon3_length))
```

I kept the parentheses in the print statements assuming you were using Python3.  You may need to change the `exon3_length` line as it was not clear to me what you intended there.

To make the code run, only two commands needed changes:

- The definition of `my_dna` is a multi-line string and hence it requires triple quotes.  On the other hand, if you intended it to be a single line string, then put it all on one line.
- The `exon3_length` line had two problems: unbalanced parens and the attempt to call an integer.

After fixing those issues, the code runs.

**The quotes and minus-signs used in your code, as opposed to the excerpt, are just fine.  Not one needed to be changed to make the code run.**

Answer (score 0):

This is the part of the code where it goes wrong:

`exon3_length = (gene_length(my_dna.find('GATCGA'))`

`gene_length` is defined as an integer earlier by calling `len` on the dna string. Also, the parentheses are not right, one is missing to close the outer one (which is redundant).

Comment: Would this work? exon3_length = (gene_length - (my_dna.find(‘GATCGA’)))

Comment: yes, but please strip the redundant parens like so `gene_length - my_dna.find('GATCGA')`